# Spring Data does not handle Pageable action argument creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a simple controller action:

```java
public class CategoriesController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "" })
    public String list(
        Model model,
        @PageableDefault(size = CategoriesController.PAGE_LIMIT) Pageable pager
    )
    {
        // load page data
        Page<Category> page = this.categoryService.findAll(pager);

        /* action logic here */
    }
}
```

Here is my `pom.xml` fragment:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

After addtion this to my `applicationContext.xml`:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration"/>
```

I have following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface
```

Spring Data itself works fine, JPA repositories are working. But until now I had hand-written pagination in controllers (calculating pages on my own, creating `PageRequest` objects by hand). I wanted to make use of Spring Data web extras, but they don't work for me for some reason... registering obsolete `org.springframework.data.web.PageableArgumentResolver` by hand partially made it working, but not completely, but still, I don't think this should even be a solution.

After enabling debug logger on `org.springframework` I see that:

```
01:37:33.850 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration.pageableResolver()
```

So it's registered - any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Add it to the configuration loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`. I assume *applicationContext.xml* is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: Isn't it equivalent? I thouht that `applicationContext.xml` is inherited by all the servlets and as long as I have just one, there is no difference between where I put the bean definition...

Anyway - I tried moving that to `mailer-servlet.xml` and the result is the same, logs look also the same (I see the bean initialized and web configuration processed, but error appears on web).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to mix XML configuration and Java Config based configuration. In this particular case that isn't going to work. The bean in the configuration class will be instantiated but that is it, they aren't registered to your `<mvc:annotation-driven />` configuration.

You will have to add the beans manually to the `ConversionService` and your `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. Either that our switch, at least your `DispatcherServlet` configuration to Java Config.

In XML you can configure additional argument-resolvers by using the `<mvc:argument-resolvers />` tag. (This mimics the configuration from the `SpringDataWebConfiguration`).

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <ref bean="sortResolver"/>
        <ref bean="pageableResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="sortResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
<bean id="pageableResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
    <constructor-arg ref="sortResolver" />
</bean>
```

However the `SpringDataWebConfiguration` does more then only these 2 resolvers it also registers a [`DomainClassConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/support/DomainClassConverter.java). If you also want to use that you need some additional configuration.

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />

<bean class="org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter">
   <constructor-arg ref="conversionService" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService">
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <ref bean="sortResolver"/>
        <ref bean="pageableResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="sortResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
<bean id="pageableResolver" class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
    <constructor-arg ref="sortResolver" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out!

Fortunately I've found out that `<mvc:annotation-driven>` element allows for customization of services mentioned by you. Here is what I needed to make it working with `<mvc:annotation-driven>`.

`
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver"/>
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
`

Thanks alot.

Comment: looks like since spring 3.0, the FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean is now packaged under org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean

Comment: @chrismarx That was actually a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If we set <property name="oneIndexedParameters" value="true"> then  what is <constructor-arg name="page" value="????" /> correct value? If I give 1 then all 0th index values will be missing...Is it ok to give 0th index?

Comment: Would you mind explaining why the ConversionService is not registered in this particular case ?

Answer (score 4):

Or you can add this to user ApplicationContext

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

it will work with Spring 4

Comment: Which is basically the same as already stated as the first solution in in my answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum only shorter