# Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When I'm sending a request like `getUserPlaces?page=0&size=5` 
I get this error:

> Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface

My controller is:

```
@Controller
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class UserController {
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUserPlaces", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<PlaceDto> getUserPlaces(@RequestBody RoutePagingDto routeRequest, Pageable pageable) {
    return placeService.placeToPlaceDto(userService.getUserPlaces(pageable));
}
```

In my spring-context.xml I have them declared beans:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver" />
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: I think `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` should be on a configuration class not here

Comment: On what  configuration class?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22143995/2286990) might be related.

Comment: @lifus it might be, but when I paste 
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <ref bean="sortResolver"/>
        <ref bean="pageableResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

It's saying that <mvc:argument-resolvers> not allowed here.
It might be because I'm using Spting 4+, have no idea, can u help me with this?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/jpa-orm/745307-beaninstantiationexception-pageable-specified-class-is-an-interface) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25380114/2286990). As @RC. mentioned, you don't need annotations like `EnableSpringDataWebSupport`, [especially on controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions).

Answer (score 4):

Remove `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` from UserController class and create WebConfig class with the following code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {}
```