# Failed to instantiate Pageable in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Data JPA starter at classpath:

`compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')`

I expected that `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration` will be automatically loaded in such situation but I'm getting:

`org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable]: Specified class is an interface`

trying to get response from one of my endpoints.

Why Spring Boot auto configuration does not work in this situation? Is it a normal behavior? Or maybe I missed something?

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Entire? :) No. What would you want specifically?

Comment: Your gradle config including versions of dependencies, your endpoint, a full stack trace might help.

Alternatively, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057262/failed-to-instantiate-pageable-bean

Comment: If this is a controller you wrote you should use the concrete type `PageRequest` which implements this interface.