# spring pagination not retrivieing data for database

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Hello I'm using spring data JPA in my sample project,when I use pagination this shows following error,However data insertion  and data retrieval(without pagination) working fine.Any help appropriated.

> stack trace

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1013)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable.<init>()
    java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:216)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:84)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.78 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.78
```

> Pserson.java

```
package core.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name="person_detail")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="adahar_id")
    private int personId;
    @Column(name="person_name")
    private String personName;
    @Column(name="person_address")
    private String personAddres;
    public int getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }
    public void setPersonId(int personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }
    public String getPersonName() {
        return personName;
    }
    public void setPersonName(String personName) {
        this.personName = personName;
    }
    public String getPersonAddres() {
        return personAddres;
    }
    public void setPersonAddres(String personAddres) {
        this.personAddres = personAddres;
    }
    public Person(int personId, String personName, String personAddres) {
        super();
        this.personId = personId;
        this.personName = personName;
        this.personAddres = personAddres;
    }
    public Person() {
        super();
    }





}
```

> PersonRepository.java

```
package core.repository;



import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import core.entities.Person;
@Repository("PersonRepository")
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
    Person findByPersonName(String personName);


}
```

> PersonService.java

```
package core.services;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;

import core.entities.Person;

public interface PersonService {
    public void createPerson(Person person);
    public Person getPersonByName(String name);
    public List<Person> getAllPersons();
    public Page<Person> getAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

> PersonServiceImpl.java

```
package core.serviceImpl;



import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import core.entities.Person;
import core.repository.PersonRepository;
import core.services.PersonService;

@Service(value="PersonServiceImpl")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;


    public void createPerson(Person person) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        personRepository.save(person);

    }

    public Person getPersonByName(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.findByPersonName(name);
    }
    public List<Person> getAllPersons() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Page<Person> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return personRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

}
```

> PersonController.java

```
package springmodule.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableDefault;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import core.entities.Person;
import core.services.PersonService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="info")
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/allpages")
    public @ResponseBody Page<Person> getAllPage(@PageableDefault(size=10,page=0)Pageable pageable ){
        return personService.getAll(pageable);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057262/failed-to-instantiate-pageable-bean/30058772

Comment: @CodeMaster thanks a lot,I was missing some configuration, above mention link helped me to pointing out my problem.